# Imprimir todo el contenido de un diccionario python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Teniendo el siguiente diccionario me gustaria imprimirlo de la siguiente forma

```
Usuario=Test
Nombre=Test
Apellido=Test
Password=1234
```

Y el resto igual

He intentado hacer `for i in d.Personal: print(f"{indice} .\n")`
Pero no logro que me quede como me gustaria

```
Personal = {
"test": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "test",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test2": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test3": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo2",
    "password": "1234"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
Personal = {
    "test": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "test",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "test2": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "kubo",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "test3": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "kubo2",
        "password": "1234"
    }
}


for ind in Personal:
    print("Usuario="+ind)
    print("Nombre="+Personal[ind]["nombre"])
    print("Apellido="+Personal[ind]["apellido"])
    print("Password="+Personal[ind]["password"])
```

Usa un `for` para recorrer cada elemento de la lista, luego imprimiremos el Usuario, Nombre, Apellido y Password

[image: Imprimir todo el contenido de un diccionario]

#### Update

Respecto a tu comentario, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
Personal = {
    "test": ["test","test","1234"],
    "test2": ["test","kubo","1234"],
    "test3": ["test","test2","1234"],
}

for ind in Personal:
    print("Usuario="+ind)
    print("Nombre="+Personal[ind][0])
    print("Apellido="+Personal[ind][1])
    print("Password="+Personal[ind][2])
```

Recorreremos `Personal` y luego imprimiremos los índices 0,1 y 2, teniendo en cuenta que: [nombre],[apellido],[password]

[image: Imprimir todo el contenido de un diccionario python]

Comment: No necesitas el `if`, ya que el `for` itera por las claves **existentes**, nunca vas a encontrar una inexistente. Por otro lado, no necesitas tampoco los `+"\n"`, pues `print()` siempre añade un retorno de carro.

Comment: @abulafia gracias por tu aporte, el "\n" lo uso debido a que estaba probando el código y no se ponían los saltos de línea

Comment: Y si tuviera el diccionario de esta manera Personal={usuario:[nombre,apellido,password]}                                                                                        Como seria para imprimirlo? Estoy probando todo el tema de los diccionarios y me ayuda mucho todo esto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Un aproximación un poco más genérica:

```
for usuario in Personal:
  print(f"Usuario={usuario}")
  for dato, valor in Personal[usuario].items():
    print(f"{dato}={valor}")

Usuario=test
nombre=test
apellido=test
password=1234
Usuario=test2
nombre=test
apellido=kubo
password=1234
Usuario=test3
nombre=test
apellido=kubo2
password=1234
```

Si no te preocupa la capitalización de los nombres de claves y eventualmente el orden de los elementos, esto básicamente itera por cada usuario y a su vez dentro de estos, por cada subdiccionario.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti tambien , esta respuesta tambien funciona perfectamente y es justo lo que queria. ¿Se pueden aceptar por validas dos respuestas?

Comment: Hola @Arturo no se puede aceptar dos respuestas solo puede haber una aceptada, pero puedes dar *upvote* a todas las respuestas que consideres. Por lo que puedes aceptar una de las dos, y darle un *upvote* y a la otra darle otro *upvote*.